# Windows Web Deploy not setting 'Connect As' user with proper Domain

Tags: powershell, iis-7, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm trying to migrate a site to a new server using Microsoft Web Deploy.  The command I'm using is the following:

```
$msdeployPath = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"

&$msdeployPath '-verb:sync' '-source:package=iisPackage.zip,encryptPassword=password,machineconfig32.netfxversion=2,machineconfig64.netfxversion=2,rootwebconfig32.netfxversion=2,rootwebconfig64.netfxversion=2' '-dest:webserver,machineconfig32.netfxversion=2,machineconfig64.netfxversion=2,rootwebconfig32.netfxversion=2,rootwebconfig64.netfxversion=2'
```

When I run it locally (on the server itself) it copies all of the site information that I want, but it sets the 'Connect As' user in the site's Basic Settings as SANDBOX\sandbox_usr.  But as I'm working on automation I'm not running the script locally, I'm executing it from a uDeploy server.  When I execute it from my uDeploy server everything gets put onto the server, but the user that's set is 'sandbox_usr' which isn't what I want.

I tried using the Authtype flag in web deploy but that didn't do it for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried starting it with start-process and pass it credentials this way? Since i dont see where you declare the user i assume it uses the user that runs the command?

Comment: @Paul the user account that's running the scripts in both local and remote script execution are SANDBOX\pcort.  What I did to get the IIS package was create a template of the IIS set up we wanted and then we're going to deploy that to servers.  

What I'm not understanding is why the domain is there when I run it locally, but not when I run it remotely.